# kimono pagination error with Amazon

Tags: pagination, web-scraping, kimono

I am trying to scrape Amazon result pages using Kimono. For instance I type "Sony" on Amazon.co.uk search engine and want to scrape the results to get product names. I am able to do it for one page but I'd like to scrape multiple pages using pagination feature. So far I can't get the pagination to work. I select "Next Page" as the link for pagination but then I get a E20 error.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Could it be the structure of Amazon pages which prevents the use of pagination feature?

Thanks!
Flo

Comment: I use Kimono using pagination to scrape pages in Amazon. How are you adding the pagination link exactly?

Comment: I used their pagination feature on the tool bar and tried selecting either the "Next page" link or the page numbers (1,2,3,...). With the first method I get a E20 error and can't get any other page than the first one. With the second method I can get only page 1 and 2 but not more than that. I tried tweaking the code manually to solve the issue but with no success.

Comment: Hmm. I use the next page link and don't get an E20. I'm not sure the best way to help with this. When you look at the API Data Model View do you see  Pagination defined in its own section at the end and the "next" key as the data for the "Pagination Link"? And in the Advanced view do you see that section defined as => Pagination Link {  li.a-last > a } { /^()(Next→)()$/}  ?  {} formatting is mine.

Comment: @ValAsensio This is what I can see in the Advanced view => Pagination Link {a.pagnNext} {/^()(Next Page)()$/}. I tried changing the code in Advanced view to use yours but stil doesn't work... My source url is http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/field-keywords=sony Is that the sort of page you are scrapping?

Comment: I took a look at the link you posted and did the pagination details, and I see that it is different from the Amazon pages I'm scraping. I'm scraping wish lists specifically. It looks like Amazon has a different paging format by type of list. '{a.pagnNext}' may be creating a problem with Kimono. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Are you able to scrape lists of ASINs by manually generating urls? No worries thanks for trying!

Comment: Here's a page I generate from Kimono scrapes : http://wishalizer.org/wishlists/amazon

Comment: This is sort of late, but if you haven't figured it out, specifying the page in the URL manually might work -> `&page=2`

Comment: Thanks this is useful!

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Seems you've encountered business directories tough case. It's almost always  scrape-proof walled/pitched. Amazon with its billions of items for sure keeps high walls against data theft and such a light scraping tool as the kimono scraper for sure (99,99%) will stumble over it.
See the [tips and tricks on scraping business directories](http://scraping.pro/business-directories-scrape-tips-tricks/).

### Quote

> Those kind of sites are especially vigilant about using anti-scraping measures to avoid data leaks. So be ready for unexpected pits falls and unbreakable firewalls...

My suggestion is you to pick any [off-the-shelf scraping software](http://scraping.pro/web-scraper-test-drive/), plug proxy service into it and go ahead scraping.